# How to dynamically add data to arrays

Tags: android, arrays, expandablelistview

I have 2 arrays in my ExpendableListView Adapter class that provide my group and child headers with dummy data.  The first array is a regular one and the second array is a 2D array.

```
public class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

String[] groupNames = {
        "Fall 2016", "Winter 2017",
        "Fall 2017", "Winter 2018",
        "Fall 2018", "Winter 2019",
        "Fall 2019", "Winter 2020"
};

String[][] childNames = {
        {"JAVA101", "MATH101", "CHEM101"},{"JAVA201", "MATH201", "CHEM201"},
        {"JAVA301", "MATH301", "CHEM301"},{"JAVA401", "MATH401", "CHEM401"},
        {"JAVA501", "MATH501", "CHEM501"},{"JAVA601", "MATH601", "CHEM601"},
        {"JAVA701", "MATH701", "CHEM701"},{"JAVA801", "MATH801", "CHEM801"}
};
```

And as required, I have implemented all of my necessary methods and have attached them to my arrays.

```
Context context;

    public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groupNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return childNames[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupNames[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childNames[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText(groupNames[groupPosition]);
        textView.setPadding(100,0,0,0);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setTextSize(20);

        return textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText("Java" + groupNames[childPosition] + "01");
        textView.setPadding(100,0,0,0);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setTextSize(10);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, textView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return textView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }
```

Everything works fine.  What I want to do, is to dynamically add data to my ExpandableListView through FAB clicks.  I'm mostly curious about if I need to implement my `onClick()` functionality of my FAB button inside my Adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of an array *cannot* be modified. If you want a bigger array you have to instantiate a new one. A better solution would be to use an [`ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which can grow as you need it.

So create a method in your adapter to add new items to your existing list. In the method add your new items to the ArrayList and call `.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Replace `groupNames` with

```
List<String> places = Arrays.asList("Fall 2016", "Winter 2017", "Fall 2017", "Winter 2018", "Fall 2018", "Winter 2019", "Fall 2019", "Winter 2020");
```

For `childNames` you have to do it like this

```
List<String[]> childNames = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"JAVA101", "MATH101", "CHEM101"}, new String[]{ "JAVA201", "MATH201", "CHEM201" } etc...);
```

OR

```
List<String[]> childNames = new ArrayList<String[]>();
childNames.add(new String[]{"JAVA101", "MATH101", "CHEM101"});
//etc...
```

You also have to change your adapter to use ArrayLists instead of Arrays, i hope you get the idea

Comment: How do I replace the two arrays (even the 2D one) with an array list?

Comment: Edited my post with an example

Comment: In the implemented methods like `getGroup()`, `getGroupView()`, `getChildView()` there are errors like the following:  

`@Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupNames[groupPosition];
    }`

Now `groupNames` does not recognize `int groupPosition`

Comment: You should read up on how to use ArrayLists. To get an item from it use `groupNames.get(groupPosition)`

Answer (score 0):

> first of all to add data dynamically use ArrayList

1. no need to implement onclick(); in adapter add data from activity onclick
2. then use notifyDatasetchanged(); on adapter this will do the trick